# How to plot biconditional graphs?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

I'm using *biconditional graphs* for the lack of a better name, I don't know the name of it, if you know the real name, feel free to edit it.

> Draw the set of points given by: $|x-3|\leq1$ and $|y-2|\leq5$

I have evaluated the values for which the conditions are true and I obtained $\{x:2\leq x\leq 4\}$ and $\{y:-3\leq y\leq 7 \}$, now I'm trying to plot as if it were a function $f(x):=|x-3|\leq1$, then I'm using the values of $y$ for making a correlation with $x$, for example:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {f(2)}&:=&{|2-3|\leq1} \\ 
  {}&:=&{1\leq 1 } 
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{1}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {f(3)}&:=&{|3-3|\leq1} \\ 
  {}&:=&{0\leq 1 } 
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2}$$

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  {f(4)}&:=&{|4-3|\leq1} \\ 
  {}&:=&{1\leq 1 } 
\end{eqnarray*}\tag{3}$$

Thus $f(2)=1$, $f(3)=0$, $f(4)=1$, but I can't find a match, because there are not $0$'s nor $1$'s in the interval $2\leq x \leq 4$, is this correct?

The secondary hypothesis I have is that this kind of operation is made to plot planes, not lines, then I should just draw a plane, is that it?

Comment: Yes, you should draw and shade in the rectangle in the Cartesian plane whose vertices are $(2,-3),(2,7),(4,-3),(4,7)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have two inequalities: solving one gives you the values of $x$ defined by the first inequality; solving the other gives you the values of $y$ defined by the second inequality. *Neither* inequality is a *function*, and so  $x$ is certainly not a function of $y$, nor is $y$ a function of $x$.

---

Try graphing the lines $y = -3$ and $y = 7$: those will be the horizontal bounds of the region defined by your inequalities. Then graph the the vertical lines $x = 2, x = 4$: giving you the bounded region of interest: the rectangular region with vertices: $$(2,-3),(2,7),(4,-3),(4,7)$$

Then simply "shade" the region bounded by these lines, inclusive of the lines.

From [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3%20%3C=%20y%20%3C=%207,%202%3C=%20x%20%3C=%204,%20) (though note the scale for the x, y axis are not matched. If you were to graph this to scale, you'd have a rectangle that is much "taller" than it is wide):

[image]

ADDED: Nicer graph of the inequalities (in that it is properly scaled):

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, Gustavo!

Comment: Amy, can you help me with one more thing? There's also an exercise with *or* instead of *and*. I'm thinking that it's plot is like a big plus sign. Is this correct?

Comment: Think of "and" as the intersection of all those regions (territory in common), and "or" as the union of all defined regions (all territory covered by one or more inequality).

Comment: Yeah. I thought about the truth tables, *and* would be the intersection, yes because $1\wedge 1=1$. I guess I've figured the answer, was asking just because Wolfram Alpha didn't show me the result.